# Python joystick emulator

Tags: python, emulation, joystick

Does anybody knows how to do control the games throw emulate some joystick or steering wheel emulators with Python, it look like that for Python we have only Linux solution, but what about Windows?

For my project I use mouse X axis to emulate steering wheel in drive simulator:
This solutions doesn't work for me (no reaction in active window):

```
pyautogui.moveTo(100, 150)
win32api.SetCursorPos((300, 200))
```

With this one: `win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE, int(1200/ 1000 * 65535.0), int(1920/ 1000 * 65535.0))` I have some difficulties with resolution and accuracy of moving.

I tried on Windows 10, VJoy https://github.com/brenttaylor/VJoy, but it doesn't work well.

Probably I'm  used wrong way to declare DLL

```
__vjoy = ctypes.WinDLL ("VJoy64.dll")
```

I'm sure it must be some work solution for this common purpose !

Comment: The core windows api for simulating mouse/keyboard is the [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx) api.  That might be what you are after. There are not a whole lot of games on Windows that require a joystick or steering wheel these days.  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I do not need the steering wheel, I need the way how to control via Python, steering for driving simulators, where usually you can use a mouse for control the wheel! That is why I need to emulate this movings smoothly.

Comment: is this just for mapping mouse to joystick or do you need to integrate it in some app of yours? Maybe you can have a look at [FreePie](https://andersmalmgren.github.io/FreePIE/)